# Finding the most common n-tuples of a list of lists where order does not matter

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am still learning to use *Mathematica* and I need some help. How could I get the most common pair, and generally the most common n-tuple of a list (row vector) given a list of lists of `m x 5` dimensions? Suppose as a sample I have a list of lists, dimension `9 x 5` of numbers

```
A = 
53  21  2   49  3
44  31  26  35  46
3   45  44  24  19
19  25  60  12  16
31  44  20  35  46
21  53  2   49  20
5   23  49  18  27
7   22  33  42  58
21  53  2   49  5
```

More specifically in *Mathematica* code:

```
A = {
 {53, 21, 2, 49, 3}, {44, 31, 26, 35, 46}, {3, 45, 44, 24, 19},
 {19,25, 60, 12, 16}, {31, 44, 20, 35,46}, {21, 53, 2, 49, 20},
 {5, 23, 49, 18, 27}, {7, 22, 33, 42, 58}, {21, 53, 2, 49, 5}}
```

Suppose I want to find the most common 4-tuple of the entire list of lists (`A`). One scenario could be `{53, 21, 2, 49}` is the most common 4-tuple of the list of lists. Another scenario could be that `{44, 31, 35, 46}` is the most common 4-tuple.

More concretely, in the given list `A` , the most common 4-tuple is `{53, 21, 2, 49}` since that 4-tuple occurs three times-- one on the *first* row, one the *sixth* row, and one on the *last* row. As you may have noticed, the order does not matter.

The second most common 4-tuple would be `{44, 31, 35, 46}` since it occurs twice--once on the *second row* and again on the *fifth* row.

And then calling on `Tally` to get a result like `{{{53, 21, 2, 49},3}, {{44, 31, 35, 46}, 2},...}`

I would like to be able to do this with 2-tuples, 3-tuples, 4-tuples, and 5-tuples. I was able to do 1-tuples trivially by using `Flatten[A]` on the list of lists then `Tally[%]`. Any guidance, tips, suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Try `Tally[Flatten[Subsets[Sort[#], {4}] & /@ A, 1]]` and report back.

Comment: will $Subsets$ and $Tally$ help? you can use $Tally[list,Sort@#==Sort@#2&]$ to ignore the order while tallying.

Comment: @J.M. reply at the same moment with same idea~ :)

Comment: Yes, @Wjx; if the OP thinks it is what he needs, you have my express permission to post that solution on my behalf. ;) Note the second argument of `Subsets[]`, BTW.

Comment: I think that did the trick! I tested the sample and it gave me the expected result. Thank you friends, I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = With[{a = #, s = #2, n = #3}, Commonest[Flatten[Subsets[Sort@#, {s}] & /@ a, 1], n]] &;

f[A, 4, 1]
```

> {{2, 21, 49, 53}}

```
f[A, 4, 2]
```

> {{2, 21, 49, 53}, {31, 35, 44, 46}}

```
f[A, 3, 2]
```

> {{2, 21, 49}, {2, 21, 53}}

```
f[A, 5, 2]
```

> {{2, 3, 21, 49, 53}, {26, 31, 35, 44, 46}}

Answer (score 4):

I still will post this answer though, fortunately, OP has already got a solution~

The following code will work:

```
Tally[Flatten[Subsets[Sort[#], {4}] & /@ A, 1]]

Tally[Flatten[#~Subsets~{4}&/@A,1],Sort@#==Sort@#2&]
```

Truely an interesting thing for @J.M. and I came up woth the same solution ay the same time. :) cheers~

Answer (score 3):

Customized function for your demand.

```
SeletSubTuple[l_,n_]:=Keys[TakeLargest[Counts[Sort/@Catenate[Subsets[#,{4}]&/@l]],n]]
```

---

## Usage

```
SeletSubTuple[A, 1]
```

> {{2, 21, 49, 53}}

```
SeletSubTuple[A, 2]
```

> {{2, 21, 49, 53}, {31, 35, 44, 46}}

If this can serve,It's my honor. :)

Comment: facinating usage of functions!

Answer (score 2):

This is just play. In the following the list A in OP is `a`:

Finding the pairwise non-empty intersections and counting:

```
tal = (Tally[
      Flatten[Outer[Intersection, a, a, 1] /. {} -> Sequence[], 
       1]] /. {__, 1} :> Sequence[])[[All, 1]];
```

Determining desired result:

```
u = tal~Join~a;
rg = RelationGraph[SubsetQ[#1, #2] && MemberQ[a, #1] && #1 != #2 &, u,
   VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[
      Framed[Style[#2, Bold], Background -> White], #] &)]
Grid[SortBy[{Length@#, #, VertexDegree[rg, #]} & /@ tal, {First, 
   Last}]]
```

[image]

Ugly but for completion:

```
fun[lst_, p_] := 
 Module[{ta = (Tally[
        Flatten[Outer[Intersection, lst, lst, 1] /. {} -> Sequence[], 
         1]] /. {__, 1} :> Sequence[])[[All, 1]], sb},
  sb = SortBy[{#, Total@Map[Function[x, Boole@SubsetQ[x, #]], a]} & /@
      ta, {Length[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} &];
  If[p == "All", Grid[sb], 
   GroupBy[sb, Length@#[[1]] & -> (## &), Last][p]]
  ]
```

Testing:

```
fun[a,4]
fun[a,"All"]
```

[image]

Comment: So with this code I can basically count all of the most common n-tuples for each `n = 1,...,5`?

Comment: @physicsmajor it counts shared proper subsets (pair wise intersections and remove diagonal elements), as graph shows. As every set is subset of itself these loops were eliminated. However, if 2 lists were replicated they could either dealt with upfront or would appear in list tal.

Comment: Oh okay. I think I see what you mean.

Comment: I'm trying to run your code, but something is going wrong when running the second block: `rg` doesn't give an output and so everything in that block after that doesn't give a valid output. I tried to see what was wrong, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @physicsmajor I am sorry for the delay in replying. I have been asleep. I have added he code for the testing. I only placed the function definition. I believe you were just running the function definition. In the above `A` has been replaced by `a`. I hope this is the issue. If not let me know. :)

Comment: Take a look the second usage of [RelationGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html).Maybe it can help a little. :)

Answer (score 1):

Post another solution by graph

```
g = SimpleGraph[
  Graph[If[SubsetQ[#1, #2], DirectedEdge[#1, #2], Nothing] & @@@ 
    Tuples[{A, Sort /@ Catenate[Subsets[#, {4}] & /@ A]}]]]
```

[image]

```
n = 1; VertexList[g, _?(Or @@ 
     Thread[VertexInDegree[g, #] == 
       TakeLargest[DeleteDuplicates[VertexInDegree[g]], n]] &)]
```

> {{2, 21, 49, 53}}

You can adjust the `n` to select the 4-tuples arisen frequency of ranking

Comment: If `A` is the list of lists I provided, what is `a` in your code? It doesn't seem to run properly. I may be doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @physicsmajor I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

( *This is an extended comment, although the code can be used to produce an answer with dataset in the question.* )

Question's request is very closely related to the fundamental task of finding frequent sets in [Association Rule Learning (ARL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning). (ARL is an approach in unsupervised machine learning.)

As far as I can tell, Mathematica does not have a dedicated built-in function for ARL, but there are enough, well performing functions for doing ARL.

The rest of this answer shows the use of the package [AprioriAlgorithm.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/AprioriAlgorithm.m), which I have used in the last five-six years; it is based on the so called [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm). More effective algorithms (and packages) for ARL exist. For example R's "arules" uses the very fast ["eclat" written in C](http://www.borgelt.net/eclat.html).

Here we generate some data using dictionary words:

```
ClearAll[A]    
A = Characters /@ DictionaryLookup["*"];
```

Here we find the frequent sets with probability of appearance greater or equal to 5%:

```
minProb = 0.05;
AbsoluteTiming[
 {ares, itemToIndexRules, indexToItemRules} = AprioriApplication[A, minProb];
]

(* {2.53581, Null} *)
```

Here are the lengths of the sets of frequent sets found:

```
Length /@ ares   
(* {22, 131, 243, 118, 8} *)
```

Here are the frequent sets with 5 elements.

```
ares[[5]] /. indexToItemRules

(* {{"a", "e", "i", "n", "r"}, {"a", "e", "i", "n", "t"}, 
    {"a", "e", "i", "r", "t"}, {"a", "e", "r", "s", "t"}, 
    {"e", "i", "n", "r", "s"}, {"e", "i", "n", "r", "t"}, 
    {"e", "i", "n", "s", "t"}, {"e", "i", "r", "s", "t"}} *)
```

Note that using the package AprioriAlgorithm.m can provide results faster that say using `Commonest` / `Subsets` because Apriori uses an argument specifying the lower threshold for the frequencies of the sets, and hence candidate sets can be very effectively eliminated.